# Python construct a dictionary data type?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm new in python, and just ran into this statement

```
data = dict( (k, v) for k, v in data.items() if v != 'null')
```

I don't really what they doing here to construct a dict. Could you explain it a bit to me? Why using for loop in dict() and why the if comes after? I didn't see anythin like this in the python docs.

Thanks guys

Comment: I always found this syntax easier to understand. Does this help?: `{k:v for k, v in data.items() if v != 'null'}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code uses the [`dict`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) constructor to create a new dictionary. The constructor can take an [iterable](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#glossary) of key, value pairs to initialise the new dictionary with. As others have pointed out, the example code has a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions) the creates this iterable of key, value pairs.

The generator expression acts a little bit like a list and could be re-written like this:

```
mylist = []
for k, v in data.items():
    if v != 'null':
        mylist.append((k, v))
```

But it never actually creates a list, it just yields each value in turn as it is processed by the dict constructor.

As for why the `if` comes after the loop, this is the syntax chosen by the python developers, so you'd have to ask them. But notice in my re-written generator expression that the `if` statement is inside (i.e. after) the for statement.

I've linked already to the section on [generator expressions in the python documentation](http://docs.python.org/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions) but at unkulunkulu's request, here's a couple more:

1. Carl's Groner's [Introduction to List Comprehensions](http://carlgroner.me/Python/2011/11/09/An-Introduction-to-List-Comprehensions-in-Python.html)
2. Fredrik Haard's [How to (Effectively) Explain List Comprehensions](http://css.dzone.com/articles/how-effectively-explain-list)

Comment: A good link to list comprehensions manual would complete the answer I guess. Upvoting in advance :D

Answer (score 3):

The argument to `dict()` is a generator expression that yields tuples consisting of key, value pairs (i.e., the `(k, v)`) drawn from `data.items()`. The `dict()` built-in function can automatically construct a dictionary object from a list or sequence of such tuples, e.g.:

```
>>> kvs = [('a', 1), ('b', 2)]
>>> dict(kvs)
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

The `if v != 'null'` qualifier instructs the generator to ignore/skip over those elements whose value (that is, the second item in the tuple) equals `'null'` (more precisely, it only yields those pairs for which the value is not equal to `'null'`).

For a much more detailed explanation of generator expressions, see [PEP 289](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/).

Comment: ah yes, you are right, I deleted my answer and upvoted yours instead.